# How to keep Run together after modification in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have the following `Paragraph` created by code in a `RichTextBox`:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Run("text1"));
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("   TEST   "));
```

This is how it looks in the XAML:

```
<Paragraph><Run>text1</Run><Run>   TEST   </Run></Paragraph>
```

When I modify the text inside the `RichTextBox` by typing, it creates a new Run *instead of modifying the current one.*

This is how the XAML looks like:

```
<Paragraph><Run>text1</Run><Run>   TE</Run><Run xml:lang="en-us"> </Run><Run>ST   </Run></Paragraph>
```

Can I somehow set the behavior **to keep together and modify the current `Run`**?

Comment: This is the default behavior. Each input creates a `Run` element. Why do you need all text to be contained in a single `Run`? You can get complete text as single string anyway, if this is what you really want. Merging all runs would require extra work. And I'm sure you don't need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Obviously* you can keep them together, you just have to set the **language** property of the `Run`:

```
Run run = new Run("   TEST   ") {  Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-us") };
paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Very intuitive, I should say….

By using this, the actual run is modified instead of being splitted to pieces.